# How to set a css property depending on desktop or mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have 2 different margin for the same div depend on mobile and desktop view.

The code below can perform a `margin-left: 70px;` on desktop.
The problem arises on mobile view, it doesn't reset to `margin-left: 0px;`

How can I do it ?

Thanks.

```
.body-container {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  max-width:1350px;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 70px;
}
.content-collapsed {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for media queries in CSS. Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not resetting margin in `.content`

You need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

The solution below uses **non-mobile approach**

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) { /*choose the width you prefer*/
  .content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">content</div>
```

The solution below uses **mobile approach** (recommended, also is the same used by bootstrap 4)

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) { /*choose the width you prefer*/
  .content {
    margin-left: 70px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)).

Example :

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 0px; /* mobile*/
}
/* screen width higher than 750px */
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  div {
    margin-left: 70px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use media query. Add:

```css
/* For mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    div {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution that worked the best for my case:

```html
    <style>
      .body-container {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        max-width:1350px;
      }
    
      .content {
        margin-left: 70px;
      }
    
      @@media (max-width: 800px) { /*choose the width you prefer*/
        .content {
        margin-left: 0px;
        min-width: 100%;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

Thank you. You made my day.